# Click event on two buttons for if else condition is not working

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Advance thanks for your help. I am not understanding why it is not working. I am a beginner and hence I am not finding the problem. Please anyone help me...

```
echo "<form method='POST'><br>
    <p>Would you Like to create your Account with Details Information<b>?
</b>
                <br><br> 
                <input type='button' id='yes' name='yes' value='Yes'/> 
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
                <input type='button' id='no' name='no' value='No'/></p>
</form>";
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['yes'])) {
          echo "Yes Clicked";
         } else if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
         echo "<br><br><p> You have successfully Registered!!!</p>";
             }
        }
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: `it is not working` does not tell us anything.  What happened?  What did you expect to happen?  What error msgs did you see in the browser/console/server logs?

Comment: Someone help me please. I am waiting for your help............

Comment: Hi, I just want to print the message "Yes Clicked" or "No Clicked" on click of two Buttons which works on if else condition. When I use input type submit it returns to the same page without printing the desired message.

Answer (score 1):

Replace button with submit

```
<input type='submit' id='yes' name='yes' value='Yes'/>  
<input type='submit' id='no' name='no' value='No'/></p>
```

Comment: Hi, I just want to print the message "Yes Clicked" or "No Clicked" on click of two Buttons which works on if else condition. When I use input type submit it returns to the same page without printing the desired message.

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
<?php

echo "<form method='POST' action='index.php'><br>
    <p>Would you Like to create your Account with Details Information<b>?
</b>
                <br><br> 
                <input type='submit' id='yes' name='yes' value='yes'/></p>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
                <input type='submit' id='no' name='no' value='No'/></p>
</form>";

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['yes'])) {
         echo "<br><br><p> Yes clicked!!!</p>";
         } else if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
         echo "<br><br><p> You have successfully Registered!!!</p>";
             }
        }

?>
```

form are trigged with input type submit , so if you want to get value of two input , they must be a submit input instead of button . in this cas , you have two input type submit , theey should be type submit with different name .that's all

Comment: in the action , put the name of your php file .

Comment: get it ,hope that be useful

Comment: Hi, I just want to print the message "Yes Clicked" or "No Clicked" on click of two Buttons which works on if else condition. When I use input type submit it returns to the same page without printing the desired message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your button's type attributes to `submit` instead of `button`, or else they won't actually submit the form.

```
<input type='submit' id='yes' name='yes' value='Yes'/>
```

Comment: Hi, I just want to print the message "Yes Clicked" or "No Clicked" on click of two Buttons which works on if else condition. When I use input type submit it returns to the same page without printing the desired message.

Comment: you sould change input type to submit for Yes and NO input .

Comment: I tried it on my test server and it definitely works as you intend it to.